# Cross tabs/frequency tables with long-form longitudinal data in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a longitudinal dataset with data in long format (one row for each time point for each participant), and I would like to get cross tabs for demographic variables at each time point. Simplified, say I wanted a table with the number of participants of a certain sex (row) and race (column) for each of 3 time points ("Time" variable).

Something like this:

```
Time = 1

        White    Black  Total
Male    10       11
Female  9        12
total   19       23     42
```

And a sample data set:

```
Participant Time Race Sex
1           1    White Male 
1           2    NA    NA 
1           3    White Male 
2           2    Black Male
2           3    Black Male
2           NA   NA    NA
3           1    Black Female    
3           NA   NA    NA
3           NA   NA    NA
```

I can do this individually by subsetting the dataset by each wave, but I was unable to figure out how to do it all together/at once, if possible, without having to subset the data into new datasets. Ideally, it would also include % in each cell and total sample sizes as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyverse`:

```
df <- tribble(~Participant, ~Time, ~Race, ~Sex,
              1,           1,    "White", "Male", 
              1,           2,    NA,      NA, 
              1,           3,    "White", "Male", 
              2,           2,    "Black", "Male",
              2,           3,    "Black", "Male",
              2,           NA,   NA,      NA,
              3,           1,    "Black", "Female",    
              3,           NA,   NA,      NA,
              3,           NA,   NA,      NA)

df %>% 
  group_by(Time, Race, Sex) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  spread(Race, count)

# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#    Time Sex    Black White `<NA>`
#   <dbl> <chr>  <int> <int>  <int>
# 1     1 Female     1    NA     NA
# 2     1 Male      NA     1     NA
# 3     2 Male       1    NA     NA
# 4     2 NA        NA    NA      1
# 5     3 Male       1     1     NA
# 6    NA NA        NA    NA      3
```

If you want to use base R:

```
df_list <- split(df, df$time)
lapply(df_list, function(x) table(x$race, x$sex))
```